# Hilt ViewModel Injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I've been trying to resolve my issue but I can't find anything...

MyApp.kt :

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp: Application()
```

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity()
```

MyFragment.kt

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

MyViewModel.kt

```
class MyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    application: Application,
    myRepository: MyRepository, {*}
    @Assisted private val state: SavedStateHandle,
): AndroidViewModel(application)
```

MyRepository.kt

```
interface MyRepository { 
    fun test()
}

class MyRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(): MyRepository { 
    override fun test() { print("") }
}
```

MyModule.kt

```
@Module 
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class MyModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsMyRepository(impl: MyRepositoryImpl): MyRepository
}
```

If I comment the line with "{*}", it works fine, but since I try to add my custom repository, I got this error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class MyViewModel

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.app.Application]

Do you have any idea of what I am missing?

Thanks you!

Complementary informations:
I forgot to mention that this is a multi module app.

In the first module, there is the basic app : MainActivity, a manifest (1)

In the second module, there is the core app : MyApp, a manifest (2)

In the third module, there is the module : MyFragment, MyViewModel, MyRepository and MyModule, a manifest (3)

Manifests are like this:

(1)

```
<manifest...>
    <application...
        android:name=".secondModule.MyApp">
</manifest>
```

(2)

```
<manifest...>
    <application>
        <provider...></provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

(3)

```
<manifest.../>
```

Comment: what do you need the interface for ?

Comment: I have simplify as much as I can my code :) I have a repository which calls an Api class, but for now I have remove it until it works

Comment: You'll need to add some build.gradle dependencies because this sounds like Dagger + Hilt version mismatch.

Comment: My current version (after IR42 answer) : Dagger : 2.31.1, Hilt : 2.31-alpha

Answer (score 0):

- First Annotate your fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
 class MyFragment: Fragment() {
  private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

- Secondly you have to extend ViewModel instead of AndroidViewModel

```
class MyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
   @Application context : Context ,
   myRepository: MyRepository, {*}
   @Assisted private val state: SavedStateHandle,
): ViewModel()
```

- Subsitute SingletonComponent With ApplicationComponent

```
 @Module 
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
abstract class MyModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsMyRepository(impl: MyRepositoryImpl): MyRepository
}
```

PS : Don't forget to add your application class( MyApp )  to your manifest file

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I have modify my two files. But I've still have this error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Fragments must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Activity MainActivity (I have the annotation "@AndroidEntryPoint" on both activity and fragment)
The thing I can't do is to use annotation "@Application", is "@ApplicationContext" the same ?

Comment: I have edited the answer again check it out and see if it works

Comment: Maybe the problem is here. It's a multi modules app. In the app module, my AndroidManifest as the attributes "android:name="MyApp"". In the other module (where the fragment belong), the manifest is almost empty, its just a declaration

Comment: can you add some code of your manifest file in your code !

Comment: For your substitute, this annotation is unknown with hilt in version 2.31-aplha

Comment: The substitute is wrong! `ApplicationComponent` is deprecated. Use `SingletonComponent`!

Comment: No it is not deprecated , make sure you have added the right dependencies

Comment: @takieddine it's deprecated since Dagger 2.30 and removed in 2.31

Comment: It's deprecated yes, I have the right dependencies. Thanks for you help, until now I haven't found anything which can make this simple code works :/ I hope I will find it soon

Answer (score 0):

You must use `@AndroidEntryPoint` for your fragments

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

Also `ApplicationComponent` was removed in `Dagger 2.30`, but it is used in `androidx.hilt:hilt` (`@ViewModelInject`).
They added `ApplicationComponent` back in `2.31.1` because of the library mentioned above.

Update your Dagger version to `2.31.1` (use `SingletonComponent` instead of `ApplicationComponent`) or use new feature [Hilt View Models](https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model)

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val application: Application,
    myRepository: MyRepository,
    private val state: SavedStateHandle,
): ViewModel()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated dagger to 2.31.1. I can use HiltViewModel annotation and I have try your solution and I still have the same issue : "IllegalStateException: Hilt Fragments must be attached to an AndroidEntryPoint Activity.", even if I have annotate all my fragments and my MainActivity with "AndroidEntryPoint".

Comment: @JohnDoe Do you have any other activities without `@AndroidEntryPoint` that use fragments with `@AndroidEntryPoint`?

Comment: Nope, I don't see any activities which hold a fragment with AndroidEntryPoint without AndroidEntryPoint too